# Parsing XML file while it is being written in Qt

Tags: c++, file, qt

I have a process that is writing an XML file. I am writing an application that wants to parse the XML that is being written. The constraint here is that I want to parse the XML as it is being written. The XML is not written entirely all at once, and will be written gradually. How can I accomplish this using Qt?

Comment: YOu need some kind of event system that will show to second application whether the file can be read or not. You can use Qt IPC mechanisms. Take a look on this page and choose one: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc.html

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qxmlstreamreader.html).  It will report a `QXmlStreamReader::PrematureEndOfDocumentError` if it runs out of data as you're parsing, but you should be able to wait for more data if this happens.

Proposed link also contains information about incremental parsing.